# Segmenting Kinect body arms

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, kinect, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment arms from a Kinect depth image in my app (click for larger picture):

[image: Red pixels are closer to the camera]

I tried using joint positions to get the vector between elbow and wrist/hand-tip, and created a 2D bounding rotated rectangle between these two joints, and then removed all pixels outside the rectangle. The problem is that, depending on the distance from the sensor, this rectangle changes width, and can become trapezoidal (e.g. if hand is closer to the camera), so it can basically only allow me to discard parts of the image before doing actual processing.

When the hand is near the body (like my left arm below), I need to detect the edge of the hand - presumably by checking the depth gradient. But I couldn't find a flood fill algorithm which "stops" at gradients.

Is there a better approach perhaps? I could use an algorithm idea.